# Invalid date error by date command

Tags: command-line, date

I want to get the date information with this command:

```
date --date=2019-03-22
```

or

```
date --date=2019/03/22
```

but it shows this error:

```
date: invalid date ‘2019-03-22’
```

or

```
 date: invalid date ‘2019/03/22’
```

as you can see it is not related to dash. the same thing happens with slash.

When I use another date like

```
date --date=2019-03-21
```

It shows the information correctly.

It shouldn't be related to the bad dash character. because I just deleted the last `2` and replaced it with `1` and the output is OK.

What is going wrong?

**Result of some commands for more information:**

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

```
$ type -a date
date is /bin/date
```

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
$ which date
/bin/date
```

```
$ apt-cache policy coreutils
coreutils:
  Installed: 8.28-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 8.28-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 8.28-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

```
$ date
Fri Mar 22 06:54:59 PDT 2019
```

```
date --date=2019-03-22 2>&1 | od -c
0000000   d   a   t   e   :       i   n   v   a   l   i   d       d   a
0000020   t   e     342 200 230   2   0   1   9   -   0   3   -   2   2
0000040 342 200 231  \n
0000044
```

Something weird going on with different timezone in this date: `2019-03-22`. I randomly changed timezone to different areas. Some of them have errors, some of them not! When I select these I have problem with that specific date:

- Los Angeles (USA)
- Shanghai (China)
- Madrid (Spain)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91416/discussion-on-question-by-ice-invalid-date-error-by-date-command).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm almost sure this is due to the changeover to Daylight Saving Time in the given timezone: effectively this means that an hour "disappears" (and hence becomes "`invalid`").

In my own timezone, DST started at 2AM on Sunday 10th March, so that hour is invalid:

```
$ cat /etc/timezone
America/Toronto
$ date --date="2019-03-10 02:00:00"
date: invalid date ‘2019-03-10 02:00:00’
```

whereas the times immediately before and after are valid:

```
$ date --date="2019-03-10 01:59:59"
Sun Mar 10 01:59:59 EST 2019

$ date --date="2019-03-10 03:00:00"
Sun Mar 10 03:00:00 EDT 2019
```

In timezones where the change over happens at midnight, the bare date appears invalid because GNU `date` assumes a time of midnight:

```
$ TZ=Asia/Tehran date --date='2019-03-22'
date: invalid date ‘2019-03-22’
```

but one hour later is valid:

```
$ TZ=Asia/Tehran date --date='2019-03-22 01:00:00'
Fri Mar 22 01:00:00 +0430 2019
```

See also [Invalid Date Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672134/invalid-date-linux)

Comment: Thanks, adding time to date fixed the problem.

Comment: They "change to daylight saving at midnight" should not be a problem for 2019-03-22 as the users TZ is currently PDT.

Comment: reinstalling `tzdata` package fixed the problem for me. Now only one timezone has error as you explained in your answer without adding time. I don't know what went wrong with `tzdata` package but even `TZ=America/Toronto date --date="2019-03-10 02:00:00"` returned the result without error before reinstalling the `tzdata` package. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ date_ascii="2019-03-22"
$ printf "%s" "$date_ascii" | od -c
0000000   2   0   1   9   -   0   3   -   2   2
0000012
$ TZ=Asia/Shanghai date -d "$date_ascii"
Fri Mar 22 00:00:00 America 2019
```

and

```
$ date_unicode="2019‑03‑22"
$ printf "%s" "$date_unicode" | od -c
0000000   2   0   1   9 342 200 221   0   3 342 200 221   2   2
0000016
$ TZ=Asia/Shanghai date -d "$date_unicode"
date: invalid date ‘2019‑03‑22’
```

Comment: Seems There is something wrong with timezone in my system :(

Comment: you should reinstall the `tzdata` package.